# Does double pendulum pass through all the points in its reagion?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, stochastic-processes

In the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1682368/d), I asked for PDF of the locus of end of a [double pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum).

Now, I am thinking about a more fundamental question. When a double pendulum moves, does its trajectory make a complete surface or a surface with a lot of wholes inside it? does the trajectory covers all points inside the envelope curve? Or even  is there a convex subsurface in the trajectory locus?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd expect it to be area-filling, and [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/physicsgifs/comments/25zedh/chaos_and_the_double_pendulum_xpost_from_rphysics/) and [this write-up it links to](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m53f09/public_html/proj/Roja_writeup.pdf) agree, but I don't know how authoritative they are.

Comment: Apart from the obvious ($l_2 \not = l_1$ restricts to within an annulus), it may depend on starting conditions: e.g. is there enough energy to go over the top, or might there be few equilibrium paths from specific starting conditions as happens in other chaotic patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The set covered by the trajectory certainly has Lebesgue measure zero: For each second $k-1\leq t\leq k$ $(k\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1})$ the corresponding part $t\mapsto \gamma(t)$ of the trajectory is a $C^\infty$ arc, hence has  measure zero. The complete trajectory is a union of countably many such arcs, hence is still of measure zero.

Of course, for most initial conditions the resulting curve will be dense in a respectable domain, but not necessarily in a full annulus.

Comment: Even if the pendulum goes for ever?